# How to change the figure size of Dataframe.hist for pandas 0.11.0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, histogram

I am trying to make histograms for a dataframe with `pandas 0.11.0` but the figure size is too small. How to change it?

In `pandas 0.19.0`, `hist` has the `figsize` parameter.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on asking a question.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Let's try something like this:

```
   fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,20))
   ax = fig.gca()
   df.hist(ax = ax)
```

Comment: Awesome. This is working exactly per plan. Thanks Scott.

Comment: Awesome. This is working exactly per plan. Thanks Scott

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the OP, since pandas 0.15.0, `df.hist(figsize=(15, 20))` or `df.plot(kind='hist', figsize=(15, 20))` is possible. Another way is to create a subplot and set figure size.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15, 20))
df.plot(kind='hist', ax=ax);
```